# remove selected options from another dropdowns using angularjs 2 filters

Tags: angular

I am able to removing the selected options from another drop down using 
angularjs 1. But how do i use same logic using angular2 filters?

can anyone help to write a filter using angular 2?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-init="foos = [{label:'label 1',id:1},{label:'label 2',id:2},{label:'label 3',id:3}]; selected = []">
  <div ng-repeat="foo in foos">
    <select ng-model="selected[$index]" ng-options="obj.id as obj.label for obj in foos | customFilter:selected:selected[$index]"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

### controller

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.filter('customFilter', function(filterFilter) {
  return function(input, filterEach, exclude) {
    filterEach.forEach(function(item) {
      if (angular.equals(item, exclude)) { return; }
      input = filterFilter(input, '!'+item);
    });
    return input;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building it using a filter I think is more clear and explicit to bind options to a method, that returns options not selected... something like:

```
getOptions() {
   return this.model.filter((el)=>{
      return !(el in this.selectedOptions);
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks jordic..but if i have 3 select boxes, we can call directly in each selectbox this way,  *ngFor="let faq of getoptions()"

Comment: If you need a more generic solution, just build a new component with your "selectbox" feature.

Answer (score -2):

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({name: 'arrayDiff',  pure: false})
export class ArrayDiffPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public array1:any=[];
  transform(array: Array<any>, diff: Array<any>): Array<any> {
    var i, item,
      newArray = [],
      exception = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    if (array && Array.isArray(array)) {
      for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        item = array[i].description;
        if(diff.indexOf(item) < 0 || exception.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
          newArray.push(item);
        }

      }
      console.log(newArray, 'newArray');
      return newArray;

    }



  }
}
```

Comment: By default, pipes are stateless/pure. Stateless/pure pipes simply transform input data into output data. They don't remember anything, so they don't have any properties – just a transform() method. 

For remembering things we have to use statefull pipes will be done in 2 ways one of them is adding a property pure: false  This will work fine :)